# Cant change element ID again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have two buttons- one to follow an id by PHP, another to Unfollow.
This is my PHP code for that-

```
 if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        echo '
        <form method="post" action="includes/follow.php" target="action" id="followform">
        <input type="hidden" name="following" value="'. $row['id'].'"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="follower" value="'.$info->id.'"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="following_name" value="'. $row['username'] .'"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="following_img" value="'. $row['u_imgurl'].'"></input>
        <button class="Follow_button" id="follow" type="submit"><table><tr><td>Follow</td><td> <img src="img/system/plus.png" width="20px"></td></tr></table></button>
        </form>';
    } else {
        echo '
        <form method="post" action="includes/unfollow.php" target="action" id="unfollowform">
        <input type="hidden" name="following" value="'. $row['id'].'"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="follower" value="'.$info->id.'"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="following_name" value="'. $row['username'] .'"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="following_img" value="'. $row['u_imgurl'].'"></input>
        <button class="Follow_button" id="unfollow" type="submit"><table><tr><td>UnFollow</td><td> <img src="img/system/cross.png" width="20px"></td></tr></table></button>
    </form>';
    }
```

The forms update the back end through an iframe. My problem was to change the buttons from Follow to Unfollow and Vice Versa.
I made a script-

```
<script>
    $('#follow').click(function(e){ 
     setTimeout(function () {
        $('form#followform').attr('action', 'includes/unfollow.php');
        $("#follow").html("<table><tr><td>UnFollow</td><td> <img src='img/system/cross.png' width='20px'></td></tr></table>");
        $('button#follow').attr('id', 'unfollow');
    }, 50);

    });
    $('#unfollow').click(function(e){ 
     setTimeout(function () {
        $('form#unfollowform').attr('action', 'includes/follow.php');
        $("#unfollow").html("<table><tr><td>Follow</td><td> <img src='img/system/plus.png' width='20px'></td></tr></table>");
        $('button#unfollow').attr('id', 'follow');
    }, 50);

    });
</script>
```

This serves my purpose, but here is the real problem-
When I click on the button once, it gives out desired appearance, but when I again click it, it does not identify the new id, thus does not change it.
The problem lies with the JQuery i suppose. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you changing the IDs? It can be done but you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Anyway to change the buttons why not just show/hide the respective forms? Changing the ID a) defeats the point of using an ID to _uniquely identify_ an element, and b) breaks the binding of the event to the element, since the element no longer matches the selector.

Comment: @ADyson that can be done... let me try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click() event will only be triggered with elements that are created already. The element that the 'unfollow' id is referring to does not exist when you bind it. Try using the event on()

```
$(document).on('click','#follow',function(e){ your code}); 
$(document).on('click','#unfollow',function(e){ your code});
```

Comment: I think it should go like this: $(document).on('click','#follow',function(e){ your code}); and  $(document).on('click','#unfollow',function(e){ your code});